# Acting via a map-acceptable abuse of language?

Tags: soft-question

Say we have some (geometric) object, let it be a binary tree $T$. Say we have a map $f$ which rotates $T$ at some certain nodes, let's say that it rotates the tree at the nodes labelled by odd numbers (assume that labelling\relabelling after rotation etc. has been appropriately fixed beforehand). Can I then say that $f$ acts on $T$ (via rotating etc. etc.)? Is such abuse of notation tolerated and understood?

Comment: I don’t see how it’s an abuse.

Comment: We usually use the term "acting" when we talk about group acting on some set, object or a ring acting on a group, etc. I was unsure if it was correct to use that term in relation with a map, even though the meaning is clear.

Comment: Well, for instance, you could say that the monoid generated by $f$ and its self-compositions acts on the graph. But I see no reason not to apply the terminology to a single map.

Comment: Ok, thank you @KevinCarlson